# Sequelize behavior on DateTime

Tags: javascript, datetime, sequelize.js

The datetime in table is 2018-01-03 15:46:59.807438 in postgres. But the result from sequelize shows time as 2018-01-03T20:46:59.807Z. I don't see any manual conversion done. Could you please help understand reason why. Somewhere i feel the time is converted to/from UTC

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres datetime shown in local timezone (to see current timezone: `show timezone;`). Response from sequelize shown in zero timezones (Z at the end of the date, ref: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z). So, it's the same date, but the first one is the date in your local timezone, the second one - UTC.